# Shinydashboard bookmarking does not bookmark the active tab if the tab is rendered from the server side

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

When a bookmarked shinydashboard with multiple tabs is loaded, the previously active tab should be active again on load - i.e., if the dashboard has 2 tabs and the bookmark button is on tab 2, tab 2 should be active when the bookmark is loaded. This works correctly if both tabs were created in the ui.

However, if tab 2 was created on the server side via renderMenu, when the bookmark is loaded tab 1 is active instead of tab 2.

The example below shows this behavior. If you move the bookmark to tab 3, it will work correctly.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

enableBookmarking(store = "server")

ui <- function(request){
    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "demo"),
        dashboardSidebar(
            sidebarMenu(id="sidebar",
                        menuItem("Static 1", tabName = "static1"),
                        sidebarMenuOutput("menu"),
                        menuItem("Static 2", tabName = "static2")
            )
        ),
        dashboardBody(
            tabItems(
                tabItem(tabName="static1", h2("something1")),
                tabItem(tabName="dynamic", h2("something2"), bookmarkButton()),
                tabItem(tabName="static2", h2("something3"))
            )
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$menu <- renderMenu({
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Dynamic", tabName="dynamic")
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I expect that a bookmark should load the active tab regardless of whether the tab was created in the ui or rendered by the server.

Edit - I tried passing the sidebarMenu id to the server as well, but that didn't work:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$menu <- renderMenu({
        sidebarMenu(id="sidebar",
            menuItem("Dynamic", tabName="dynamic")
        )
    })
}
```

Comment: The problem here will be, that the li-tag created on the server-side (by `menuItem`) is not yet existing in the DOM when shiny tries to restore the saved session.